# Is it possible to get ticker of bitcoin.de using an api?

Tags: api, marketplace

I did not found anything in the site. They have an api? It is for my Android App Bitcoin Paranoid.

Comment: This is the most-requested feature at the moment: https://getsatisfaction.com/bitcoinparanoid/topics/add_new_exchange_bitcoin_de

But I can't find a way to get the value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just parse the website. For example to get the current euro and us dollar prices:

```
curl -s https://www.bitcoin.de/de | sed -n '/EUR/s%.*[^0-9]\([0-9]\+\)\(,\)\([0-9]\+\).*%\1.\3%p'

curl -s https://www.bitcoin.de/de | sed -n '/USD/s%.*[^0-9]\([0-9]\+\)\(,\)\([0-9]\+\).*%\1.\3%p'
```

Answer (score 0):

They do have an [API](https://www.bitcoin.de/en/api/tapi/v1/docu) now. To get the the **recent trades** you could use the [`showPublicTradeHistory`](https://www.bitcoin.de/en/api/tapi/v1/docu#scrollNav-5-3) API endpoint at: `https://api.bitcoin.de/v1/trades/history`.